# Quickblox receive silent push iOS

Tags: ios, push, audio, quickblox, silent

I'm using [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/) for chat and push notifications and I would like to let the users turn on/off push sounds from my app. (which means that the notifications should be silent)

Is there a way to set sounds off from arriving push notifications with Quickblox?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chat 2.0 (automatic push notifications for offline user.), you can set sounds off in Alerts tab, in Admin panel http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Alerts

If you send push notifications from application code - you can manage push payload by yourself

Comment: Hey Igor, thank you for your answer.
I'm trying to allow the user to turn on and off the sounds he receives. I'm trying to do it using: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
We'll see how it goes...